# Rspec mock service and receive integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to mock a service that will returns the integer `1`. In an endpoint it's called

```
CompanyNameFetcher.new(params[:filters][:company_name].downcase).call
```

and all of this line I want to mock to receive `1`

This is what I have so far:

```
      let(:company_name_fetcher) do
        class_double CompanyNameFetcher
      end
      before do
        allow(company_name_fetcher).to receive(:new).and_return { 1 }
      end
```

With error

> Failure/Error: allow(company_name_fetcher).to receive(:new).and_return { 1 }
>
> ArgumentError:
> wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1+)

Comment: I think you want `CompanyNameFetcher` to receive `:call` and return `1`, right? Apparently, `new` requires some arguments, and you're not passing them in. Thus, the error, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to mock a service that will returns the integer 1. In an endpoint it's called
>
> ```
> CompanyNameFetcher.new(params[:filters][:company_name].downcase).call
> ```
>
> and all of this line I want to mock to receive 1

## Option 1 - allow_any_instance_of

```rb
allow_any_instance_of(CompanyNameFetcher).to( 
  receive(:call).and_return(1)
)
```

## Option 2 - stub the constructor

```rb
mock_fetcher = instance_double(CompanyNameFetcher)
allow(CompanyNameFetcher).to( 
  receive(:new).and_return(mock_fetcher)
)
allow(mock_fetcher).to rececive(:call).and_return(1)
```